# How to hide the colored zeros on RSI bar

Tags: pine-script

I am using '[fikira] RSI + Divergences' indicator. [Link and code here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/bzK0HvhO-fikira-RSI-Divergences/)

I have edit the code and changed colors etc.

Trying to hide the colored zeros (0.00) of regular and hidden bull and bears divergences numbers from the RSI line. (except the first yellow RSI of course)

[Here is a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELjgA.png)

Any advice please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly, do you want to eliminate the arrows that appear in that rsi? In that case you just have to delete these plotchar:

```
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_1 and not div_bull_1[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 1",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.green, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_2 and not div_bull_2[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 2",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.green, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_3 and not div_bull_3[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 3",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.green, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_4 and not div_bull_4[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 4",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.lime, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_5 and not div_bull_5[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 5",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.lime, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_6 and not div_bull_6[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 6",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.lime, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_7 and not div_bull_7[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 7",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.aqua, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bull_8 and not div_bull_8[1] and show_div, char="↑︎︎", title="Bull Div 8",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.aqua, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)

plotchar(arrows and div_bear_1 and not div_bear_1[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 1",
 location=location.top, color= color.orange, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bear_2 and not div_bear_2[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 2",
 location=location.top, color= color.orange, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bear_3 and not div_bear_3[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 3",
 location=location.top, color= color.orange, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bear_4 and not div_bear_4[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 4",
 location=location.top, color= color.red, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bear_5 and not div_bear_5[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 5",
 location=location.top, color= color.red, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bear_6 and not div_bear_6[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 6",
 location=location.top, color= color.red, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bear_7 and not div_bear_7[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 7",
 location=location.top, color= color.purple, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and div_bear_8 and not div_bear_8[1] and show_div, char="↓︎︎", title="Bear Div 8",
 location=location.top, color= color.purple, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)

plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_1 and not hid_div_bull_1[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 1",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_2 and not hid_div_bull_2[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 2",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_3 and not hid_div_bull_3[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 3",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_4 and not hid_div_bull_4[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 4",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_5 and not hid_div_bull_5[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 5",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_6 and not hid_div_bull_6[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 6",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_7 and not hid_div_bull_7[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 7",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
plotchar(arrows and hid_div_bull_8 and not hid_div_bull_8[1] and show_hiddiv, char="↑︎︎", title="Hidden Bull Div 8",
 location=location.bottom, color= color.white, size=size.tiny, transp=0, offset=-1)
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so easy... Didn't realize that if I was remove arrows then these numbers would also removed. Thank you so much Sebastian appreciate it!

Comment: just in case, if I remove that code the arrows also will be removed. Is there any way to keep arrows and only hide these zeros? Thanks in advance.